# How to connect to another Ubuntu machine using the same router but one is connected through LAN and the other is through WLAN?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, router

I am connected to a router with a wired LAN running Xubuntu and another machine running Ubuntu is connected to the same router through Wifi Netowrk. So how can I connect to that machine for shared folder access? Both machines can ping the router and can go to the internet through that router but can not ping each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"MultiAP Isolation" option was enabled in wifi section of my router, thats the reason behind no ping between lan to wlan, I disabled that option and created one normal user on each machine, added the lines for local ip series like "sshd: 192.168.5." & "vsftpd: 192.168.5." in /etc/hosts.allow file as DHCP is enabled in router otherwise for a static ip, I could add the specific ip in hosts.allow rules. And added "ALL: ALL" in /etc/hosts.deny file to prevent any other connection other than from the desired ones and used "Remmina" through "sftp protocol" to login to the other machine and exchanged files, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If the two machines are in the same network (same ip adress range), it does not matter if connected with lan or wlan.

What does you mean with connect? There are different methods to "connect".

One is VNC There for you have to install a vnc-server on one machine and 
a vnc-client on the other. Then you can connect via vnc and remotly connect to the xserver(desktop).

Another method is to use SSH(SecureShell). Then you can connect to the terminal of the server machine.

Comment: By "connect" I meant remote desktop or shared folder access of the other machine.